# How to clear cache on Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i want to use this code but it only erase caches on mozilla browser.I want to use it for IE

Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Comment: Could you please clarify what sort of cache you're trying to clear? Are you trying to clear the user's cookies for your site? Are you trying to make sure that next time the user visits your site he gets a new version of the SL app?